# Do Google/Apple provide the multiplayer servers for an app themselves?

Tags: android, networking, ios, server, mobile

I have an app that I have been working on and I was wondering does Google/Apple host the server requirements for the multiplayer aspects of an app?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you will find a free service for your hosting needs.

[Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/products/) might not be free, but it has some appealing features. They're currently running a 60 day free trial campaign, and if you decide to keep it, prices are not too high. At Google Cloud you don't pay a fixed monthly price. You pay based on load and usage.

Another option could be a discount provider like [OVH](https://www.ovh.ie/). OVH have some pretty cheap VPS, and the performance is okay. The cheapest is only 2.99€/month +  tax and includes "unlimited" bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Amazon web services. They offer "free" services until you reach a certain tier. Many companies do this. Another good one for games would be Unity as well. They are free until you start making a decent amount of money or have a certain number of users.

Answer (score -2):

No, Apple and google do not have free server solutions for apps. That would cost the money, something they want to keep.